# Google Sheet Script Incrementing Not working the way its expected but its concatinating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-editor

Google Sheet Script should increment the value of the column 1 by 1, but it is concatenating 1. I am not great at google Scripts. Could you help me find what am i Doing wrong.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var columnNumber = 1; // first col is 0
  var initialId = 18;   
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var id = sp.getProperty("req_id") || initialId ;
  id = id.split(".")[0] ;
  e.range.offset(0, columnNumber, 1, 1).setValue(id);
  sp.setProperty("req_id", id + 1);
}
```

The output is looking like this in the sheet

```
1811
18111
181111
18111111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the value to the cell and you want to add `1` every run.
- You want to use PropertiesService for this situation.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your issue is that the values retrieved by `getProperty()` is the string type. In this case, even when the number is put with `setProperty()`, when the value is retrieved with `getProperty()`, the retrieved value is the string type.
- When the number is used for `split()`, an error occurs. Because `split()` is used for the string.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var columnNumber = 1; // first col is 0
  var initialId = 18;
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var id = Number(sp.getProperty("req_id")) || initialId; // Modified
  e.range.offset(0, columnNumber, 1, 1).setValue(id);
  sp.setProperty("req_id", id + 1);
}
```

#### References:

- [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties.html#getProperty(String))
- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed briefing. Worked !!

Comment: @indianwebdevil Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.